How Do You Write the Word Form of Decimal Numbers in British English?
In British English, to write the word form of the number 109,236, you would write "one hundred and nine thousand, two hundred and thirty-six". The format and usage of "and" is consistent when there are no decimal values.
However, a problem arises when one compares the usage of "and" in the word form of numbers in American English versus British English. Because in American English, "and" is only used to denote a decimal point.
For example, if the number was instead 109,236.29086, while in American English it is clear that the word form of this number is "one hundred nine thousand, two hundred thirty-six and twenty-nine thousand, eighty-six hundred-thousandths", in British English it is unclear what the grammatically correct word form of this number is, due to the awkward placements of "and" that arise.
To express the number 109,236.29086 in British English, does one write "one hundred and nine thousand, two hundred and thirty-six, and twenty-nine thousand and eighty-six hundred-thousandths", or "one hundred and nine thousand, two hundred and thirty-six and twenty-nine thousand, eighty-six hundred-thousandths", or "one hundred and nine thousand, two hundred and thirty-six, and, twenty-nine thousand and eighty-six hundred-thousandths", or something else?
The second expression comes up when I've used this question as a prompt for a chat AI. It insists that in British English, I would either resort to expressing the decimal values as "point two nine zero eight six" or that I write "one hundred and nine thousand, two hundred and thirty-six and twenty-nine thousand, eighty-six hundred-thousandths" in exactly that form. I'm asking this question here to verify if the latter is actually the correct grammar in formal British English.
Addendum: In this post I have used the technically incorrect internet convention of placing punctuation outside of quotation marks, and I have done this explicitly for the purpose of clarity. I'm fully aware that this is "incorrect" in standard English with respect to the convention in print or formal writing.

I think, in reality, no one would spell out the decimal fractions in the case of your example number. It'd be "point two, nine, zero, eight, six".

While I agree, I'm asking specifically about what is correct in the quixotic case if and when someone does say or write out such a number in the word form.

It seems quite conceivable that even "correct" language may yield ambiguous numbers.

From my understanding, the intent of the standardization in American English to omit the older convention of using "and" to separate, for example, "two hundred and thirty-six" (in American English you would say "two hundred thirty-six") and exclusively use "and" to denote the decimal point was for the sake of clarity. This standardized form is the one currently taught to grade students in the US. However British English retains the aforementioned usage of "and", and I personally find it to be more "grammatically correct" with respect to "English" as an abstract object.

The central contention of my question is that I believe the British convention introduces a point of grammatical difficulty when it comes to expressing numbers with decimals.

Upon closer analysis, you are correct that the British convention retains ambiguity that has been removed in the American standardized form. An example is that "twenty-nine thousand and eighty-six hundred-thousandth" can refer to either 0.29086 or 29000.00086 in British English, whereas in the American standardized form it refers only to 29000.00086.

when you're reading out a decimal fraction (you would never ever write one in words but you might read it), you read out each digit after the point separately including zeros without any hundreds, thousands, etc. I don't know if you're trying to ask how to pronounce a compound fraction (mixed number) but if you want to know that, then ask that.

'While I agree, I'm asking specifically about what is correct in the quixotic case if and when someone does say or write out such a number in the word form.' I'd say you're rather asking for the read-out version of the vulgar decimal 109, 236 29086/100 000 (sorry I can't format clearly).

@EdwinAshworth ²⁹ ⁰⁸⁶⁄₁₀₀ ₀₀₀ₜₕ. I don't really buy this idea that American English somehow "standardized" any of this. Nobody would, or at least should, consider forms with and as “wrong”: certainly they were commonly heard when I was a child, and sometimes still are. Perhaps this is just more of the silly fake tyranny of Microsoft checkers and such that think they "know" things which they do not. It's not possible to impose something on people; you can only note trends.

When writing out the amount in words on a U.S. check, "and" is used correctly only to separate the dollars from the cents, in other words, it's the decimal point. I also learned convention this for decimal numbers in general.

British English uses the word "point" to represent the decimal point, and the following digits are read out singly.  See http://teach.files.bbci.co.uk/skillswise/ma04deci-e3-f-the-decimal-point-and-reading-decimals.pdf published by the BBC
So the AI's first option is correct.  The second one, using the word thousandth, is incorrect.  Thousandths are only used to represent written fractions  e.g. 1/1000 is one thousandth.  There is a unit which is only used technically, the "thou", which means a thousandth of an inch. https://www.higherprecision.com/learning-center/glossary/thou-001

So what you are saying is that to your best knowledge, British English has no equivalent convention to American English, where decimal values are read out in the manner of a fraction?
Since, 0.29086 or "twenty-nine thousand, eighty-six hundred-thousandth" is the same as 29,086/100,000. And "hundred-thousandth" is in fact the name of the place value at 0.0000x, even in British English.
But a less nauseating example would be that the place value at 0.0x is called "hundredth."

@Gnosis Your question is discussed at Word Reference Forums -> https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/topic-summary-numbers-reading-speaking-saying-writing-in-full-number-say-speak-read-write.15/#post-8805504 with additional reading. "In AE, numbers with up to three digits to the right of the point may sometimes be read as decimal fractions.​".  It is not used with decimals of more than 3 digits.

@Greybeard Thank you for the reference. I think I'm slowly becoming more convinced that there is in fact no convention for pronouncing decimal values as fractions in British English.

@Gnosis Indeed, BE does not confuse decimals and fractions. Before the conversion from Imperial to metric, school rulers (and most others) were marked in eighths or sixteenths of an inch. Tenths of an inch was very rarely used or seen. That said, in engineering, hundredths and thousandths of an inch were used.

@Gnosis That's correct. I'm a 70 year old Brit with a degree in computing, and had never come across the idea of reading out decimal values in the manner of a fraction until I read your question.  And British rulers still are commonly marked half in sixteenths of an inch and half in tenths, as well as in centimetres.

I'm going to attempt to answer my own question. Note that "American English" in this case does not refer to colloquial English spoken in the United States (which may use the British English convention), but rather the standardized spoken word form of numbers that is taught to grade school students or used in, for instance, accounting or writing checks in the United States.

For the number 109,236:

In American English: one hundred nine thousand, two hundred thirty-six.
In British English: one hundred and nine thousand, two hundred and thirty-six.

For the number 109,036:

In American English: one hundred nine thousand, thirty-six.
In British English: one hundred and nine thousand, and thirty-six.

For the number 109,236.29086:

In American English: one hundred nine thousand, two hundred thirty-six and twenty-nine thousand, eighty-six hundred-thousandths.
In British English: one hundred and nine thousand, two hundred and thirty-six point two nine zero eight six.

For the number 109,036.29086:

In American English: one hundred nine thousand, thirty-six and twenty-nine thousand, eighty-six hundred-thousandths.
In British English: one hundred and nine thousand, and thirty-six point two nine zero eight six.

For the fraction 109,236 ²⁹ ⁰⁸⁶⁄₁₀₀ ₀₀₀:

In American English: one hundred nine thousand, two hundred thirty-six and twenty-nine thousand, eighty-six hundred-thousandths.
In British English: one hundred and nine thousand, two hundred and thirty-six (verbally pause here when reading) and twenty-nine thousand, and eighty-six hundred-thousandths.

For the fraction 109,036 ²⁹ ⁰⁸⁶⁄₁₀₀ ₀₀₀:

In American English: one hundred nine thousand, thirty-six and twenty-nine thousand, eighty-six hundred-thousandths.
In British English: one hundred and nine thousand, and thirty-six (verbally pause here when reading) and twenty-nine thousand, and eighty-six hundred-thousandths.

I actually seem to remember being taught in grade school that both forms are correct. Certainly both are used across registers. I doubt anybody considers the film title "One Hundred and One Dalmatians" the least bit unusual or wrong or even informal.

I never claimed either were incorrect or informal. I'm mainly trying to process and reconcile information that is contradictory. As for registers and more granular specifics, I'd be more than happy to accept as an answer of this question, a detailed and accurate answer going into all such specifics. Hopefully you're able to see the double-standard being applied here. Instead of taking the effort to write an answer that is detailed and accurate, it is easier to downvote on the slightest impression of feeling like something is off.

Either way, I accept that the premise of the question was wrong in the first place, which is why I am using the term "American English" here, in a sense that is basically wrong. Frankly I should have never even asked the question, given the responses of negativity and confusion to it.

The commentariat here can, sadly, be less than welcoming. But it's hard to give a decent answer to a question that seems based on a false premise.
